# HTTPS availablity of http url

Tags: c#, http, https

I am having list of http urls, I need to find https url is available or not. Example : http://www.apra.gov.au/Insight/Pages/insight-issue2-2017.html, need to check whether https is available on the same domain via c# code. since I have a list of 5k http urls. I need to verify all these url available on HTTPS?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of your progress so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do a simle string replace (http: = https: ) and then loop through them all calling httpget to check:

Psuedo code:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient()
foreach(var url in urls)
   var httpUrl = url.Replace("http:","https:");
   httpClient.Get(url);
```